# Directions Api Params

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I wanted to use google map directions API and draw pessimistic traffic poly-lines. [I looked at this URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.0050506,29.0680688&destination=41.011522,29.983513&sensor=false&trafficModel=pessimistic

I created API above for pessimistic traffic. But there is no difference between best_guide or optimistic. I don't know, There is something wrong with URL?

```
{
  origin: 'Chicago, IL',
  destination: 'Los Angeles, CA',

  provideRouteAlternatives: false,
  drivingOptions: {
    departureTime: new Date(/* now, or future date */),
    trafficModel: 'pessimistic'
  }
}
```

I guess trafficmodel param must be in drivingOptions. Can anybody help me to create url like this above .

Thanks for any suggestion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is from the documentation, Google will use data available to it, If Google doesn't have enough data for that particular route, **it will return estimates**, so these are **estimates**

Also please note:

- Lat longs you are using are **not very far under ~2km**, try route for bigger distance say 25 km
- You should **try another route where you know traffic is more**, you might get different results

> - bestguess (default) indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be the best estimate of travel time given what is known about
>     both historical traffic conditions and live traffic. Live traffic
>     becomes more important the closer the departureTime is to now..
> - pessimistic indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be longer than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional
>     days with particularly bad traffic conditions may exceed this value.
> - optimistic indicates that the returned duration_in_traffic should be shorter than the actual travel time on most days, though occasional
>     days with particularly good traffic conditions may be faster than this
>     value.